# How do I find all the primes that are 1 less than a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need some help with the problem in the topic (find all the primes that are 1 less than a perfect cube). So far I can see that if we let $a$ be some positive integer, then we are looking for all primes $p$ such that $p = a^3 - 1$. I'm not sure exactly how to show all of these primes however.

Any help would be much appreciated. If you are willing to give hints rather than a straight answer, that would also be appreciated, as I want to work through as much as I can.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^3-1$ can be factored as $(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$.

Answer (score 5):

First we will factorize: 
$$p=n^3 -1$$
$$p=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$

$p$ is prime, and hence has only $p$ as a prime factor(itself), hence we can see that,$(n-1)=1$, and thus $n=2$. $p=(2-1)(2^2+2+1)=1*7=7$

$p=7$ is the only such prime that is one less than a perfect cube.